# Magento taking too much time

Tags: magento-1.7, configurable-product

I am having site on which i am having configurable product with 7000 simple product . I having problem that magento taking too much time load list view page and some time it will give the error "site taking too much load" . Site load fast when i am try to go to category in which product is not available but it take time to load login page . Can you help me out, how can i improve the speed ? I have installed the http://www.extendware.com/full-page-cache-magento-extension.html but no change.

Comment: remove the ->load() from the product list template

Comment: You need more hosting, processing that many simples is both db and cpu intensive. You need to split out the mysql and web server, normally we would say 0.5-1% of revenue for hosting but with 7000 simples we could easily see that double. It is the cost of what you are trying to do, the other option is to change the business process of how you list your products, a full page cache will not help as you have found out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Essentially the problem is that there is some less-than-optimal iterative loading.

This has been encountered by several people, and has received a decent writeup & solution over at [Turnkeye's blog](http://turnkeye.com/blog/magento-perfomance-optimization-of-configurable-products/). It is also addressed and patched on the Magento GitHub account [here](https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/90).

You might also consider adding a cache key to the collection in order to cache the results.

Comment: can database query cache help me out or not ?

Comment: Speed Increase!!!! Lot.....

Answer (score 1):

Limit your catalog product collection by any one of this methods,

setPageSize()

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();
$collection->setPageSize(50);
echo $collection->count(); // will echo 50
```

setPage()

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();
$collection->setPage(0,20); // will bring back the first 20 products
$collection->setPage(10,5); // will bring back 5 products after the 10th product
```

getSelect()->limit()

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();
$collection->getSelect()->limit(50); // will bring back our first 50 results
```

may this help you..

Comment: I have lot of product what happen to other product 50 product load ?

Comment: limit with some value what you like not by 50, based on time load set limits